# Format 1-dim tables into multiple lines

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have been using `printr` to render nice tables in the markdown output.

I have got a nice table in the `rmarkdown` pdf output.

```
table(sample(LETTERS, 200, replace = TRUE))
```

[image]

However, in this case, the output is not a nicer fit to the output.

```
table(sample(stringi::stri_rand_strings(20, 3), 200, replace = TRUE))
```

[image]

How to print the table into multiple lines if the width is exceeding the page width?

Comment: You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385696/how-to-adjust-the-output-width-of-rstudio-markdown-output-to-html)

Comment: I tried different values (eg: `options(width = 10)`) and it did not work for the tables in pdf output.

Comment: If you can use xtable... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507191/automatically-adjust-latex-table-width-to-fit-pdf-using-knitr-and-rstudio

Comment: I am getting the latex code as output instead of a table.

Comment: `options(width)` won't do anything in this case. I guess there isn't a solution unless you reorganize your table to make it narrower (e.g. manually split the table into multiple lines and create one table per line).

Comment: Thanks @Yihui. I will consider it transposing before printing. Also, I observed it is the same with the code(a line having more length than page width) in the chunks. Does this have any workaround(s)?