# [rmarkdown]How to deal with table in beamer_presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer

When I embed a table generated by using knitr::kable,
I want to adjust the width of the table in beamer_presentation's slide.

Like this picture,   some columns don't show in slide when executing the following codes.
[image]

Could you tell me how to solve this problem without changing column's names?

````
---
title: "test"
author: "test"
date: "`r Sys.time()`"
output:
   beamer_presentation:
     latex_engine: xelatex 

fontsize: 6pt 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning =  FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(include =  FALSE)
 
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

```


## Table
```{r test, results = "asis",include=TRUE}

test_tbl = tibble(
  example_name1 = c("a", "b"),
  example_name2 = c("aa", "bb"),
  example_name3 = c("aaa", "bbb"),
  example_name4 = c("aaaa", "bbbb"),
  example_name5 = c("aaaaa", "bbbbb")
)


knitr::kable(test_tbl, format = "markdown")
```
````

Comment: Can you show the resulting .tex code? You could choose a smaller font size, rotate the column names or rearange the layout of your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is too large to fit on one slide. By adjusting the font size with `kableExtra` the size of the table can be changed. To do this, set the argument `format = "latex"` in `kable()` and then pipe `kable_styling()`.

```
knitr::kable(test_tbl, format = "latex") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 7)
```

It is useful to include LaTeX packages like `booktabs` to format tables nicely with `kable` or `kableExtra`.  This is not as flexible as working with LaTeX directly but often leads to quite good results.

First of all, include `booktabs` in the YAML header.

```
---
title: "test"
author: "test"
date: "`r Sys.time()`"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
output: beamer_presentation
---
```

Then set `booktabs = TRUE` in `kable()`.

```
knitr::kable(test_tbl, format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I successfully do that.